# Split a List<String> into sublists based on length of string using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, sublist

Pretty self explanatory...

This:

```
{"hello","this","is","an","example","string"}
```

Would return:

```
{
    {"is","an"},
    {"this"},
    {"hello"},
    {"string"},
    {"example"}
}
```

Comment: noones said it yet but... what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `GroupBy`:

```
var groups = theList.GroupBy(i => i.Length);
```

Comment: Wow...I over-thought that.

Comment: I had no idea what was being asked until I spent some time thinking about this answer.

Comment: @Wilson ROFL, we've all been there.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "hello", "this", "is", "an", "example", "string" };
var listOfLists = list.GroupBy(s => s.Length)
                      .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                      .Select(g => g.ToList())
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: I'd add `.OrderBy(s => g.Length)` before `.GroupBy(s => s.Length)` to sort it.

Comment: @NickGotch: I would order the groups by `OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)`. Then the `GroupBy` would have done preliminary work.

Answer (score 1):

`GroupBy` the length of the strings:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(s => s.Length).Select(g => g.ToArray());
```

This would result in an `IEnumerable<string[]>` where each string array contains strings with the same length. Season to taste.